# how to create Setup for a WPF application which calls a console app

Tags: wpf, database, service, reference

how to create a setup for a WPF application which calls a console application.The console application has a database part and also has a WCF service reference

Answer (score 0):

You can use Process Class see the below link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326949(v=vs.71).aspx